# To give a whizz?

Tags: meaning, expressions, american-english, slang

I cannot translate it to my native language, the meaning of "to give a whizz". Could someone please explain, what does it mean, with some examples? And, is this US or world expression?

Here are some sentences from Internet that I couldn't understand:

1. Always **give a whizz** in the mixie before using it.
2. I don't **give a whizz** about the so-called “no better than a placebo.”
3. The graphic is pretty good, just want to **give a whizz.**
4. So I decided to **give** Performance Analyser **a whizz**.

Comment: It means to *try something out*. (But your first example uses the word more literally and your second uses it as a euphemism.)

Comment: I would not want to drink something somebody had *whizzed* in.

Comment: Actually number 2 is different. See [noun3 in Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/whizz)

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Number 2 Is ***way*** different.  whizz typically refers only to number 1. ;-)

Comment: surprising lack of references for the multiple meanings intended in the question samples.

Comment: I don't give a whizz for [whatever] is an euphemism for give a sh**. Also, I want to give the graphic a whirl. That is, to try it.

Comment: In the early 1970s the U.S. comedy troupe Firesign Theater occasionally referred to an imaginary product named [Bear Whiz Beer](https://books.google.com/books?id=bbcBCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA131&dq=%22bear+whiz+beer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjizoyo4prdAhVlNn0KHey4CQQQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22bear%20whiz%20beer%22&f=false). Its slogan—"It's in the water—that's why it's yellow"—is a takeoff on the actual slogan for Olympia Beer: "It's the water." More common than "give a whiz" (= "care") in U.S. slang is "take a whiz" ("urinate"), although that expression may be less common than it was several decades ago.

Answer (score 1):

"Whizz" or "whiz" is American slang for urine. "I don't give a whizz" means the matter is of no importance to me. It is a coarse expression, not fit for business letters or courtrooms.

Your first example is not a coarse expression. There, whizz is a verb meaning to mix rapidly, typically while cooking. "Mixie" is mixer. The rhythm of this example suggests a British speaker, especially one who is talking to a child.

Examples #3 and #4, the expression means to try it or to use it. More often, you would hear "give it a whirl".

Contrast this with "whiz kid", which means like a genius.

English can be very strange.

Comment: Yeah, I'd regard "give a whiz" as a slightly less "discolored" version of "give a piss" or "give a shit".  Whiz/whizz has several other meanings, though, depending on context.

Comment: I'm British, I've never heard a food mixer referred to as a "mixie". Perhaps it's an Australian or New Zealander term, they seem to have a bit of a prediliction for diminuatives.

Comment: My mother-in-law from Lancashire had the habit of adding "ie" to nouns. Examples: "Tina, time for wakies" instead of  time to wake, and "Duchess, walkies" to her dog. I heard this construction in the town of St. Anne's on the Sea.